# Windows shares keep dropping from OS X

Tags: macos, network, windows, sharing

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine providing shares for multiple workstations.

I have 2 Mac users that connect to this server and use the shared folders. They report that this share keeps dropping. Everytime they report it, I check from my Windows workstation and the shares appear to be online -- there seems to be no issue.

Is there anything I can do to make the mounted share consistent and not disappear? The issue is only on the Macs.

Both are running OS X v10.9.3

Comment: Are the devices connected via WiFi, or Ethernet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problems with users on my network using Mavericks, where no such issue existed with Mountain Lion. Most users can live with it, and they simply re-mount the disk. Apparently, the SMB implementation on Mavericks is different than it was in prior OS releases. What I have found is that if I connect to drives using **cifs://servername** rather than **smb://servername**, this pretty much mitigates the issue. This has been true for NAS, MFDs with Windows shares, and Windows servers alike.

Comment: Thanks Dave I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes.